# Exposing Swift internal func to Objective-C file(in framework) without making it public

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, header, generated

I have a Swift framework in which I have an Objective-C file. From that file I want to access a method which is declared as internal. I know that I can change it to public to make it available. But I don't want to expose it to the client app. Is there any way to achieve this?

In .swift:

```
@objc internal class func callBack(str: String) {
    print("Swift method was called | Passed value: " + str)
}
```

In .m:

```
- (void)callSwiftFunc {
    // This is not available, only if I set public in Swift
    [SwiftClass callBackWithStr:@"blabla"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the objc selector and then add a category which declares the method:

replace `@objc` with `@objc(callBackWithStr:)`, then simply add a forward declaration:

```
@interface SwiftClass ()
+ (void)callBackWithStr:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a little bit "hardcoded", but works and it's the best alternative that I've tried so far.

Comment: Hiii .please can u give me a sample code.